# default destructor in a struct containing a unique_ptr causes compilation errors when using an std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, destructor, unique-ptr

Considering the following code example, why does the definition of a default destructor cause a compilation error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

struct Foo
{
    char c;
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;

    Foo(char c_, int n_) : c(c_), ptr(std::make_unique<int>(n_))
    {;}

    //~Foo() noexcept = default; // problem here, why?
};


int main()
{
    std::map<int, Foo> mp;

    mp.emplace(0, Foo{'a',40});
    mp.emplace(1, Foo{'b',23});

    for (auto &&i : mp)
        std::cout<< i.first << " : {" << i.second.c << "," << *(i.second.ptr) << "}" <<std::endl;
}
```

Compiler error:

> error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Foo'

From the error message I get that there's a silent copy happening???

It is worth mentioning that the code compiles fine when using a normal pointer instead of a `unique_ptr`. But I do not understand why the default destructor would be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you define a destructor yourself then the compiler will no longer generate the copy-con and the move-con for you. You can specify them as default and deleted (even though the copy con will still be implicitly deleted cause of the `unique_ptr`) and your code will work again:

```
struct Foo
{
    char c;
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;

    Foo(char c_, int n_) : c(c_), ptr(std::make_unique<int>(n_))
    {;}

    ~Foo() noexcept = default;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
};
```

This'll also be the case for `operator=(Foo&&)`.

Comment: Of course!!! Aaaarg!!! Now I remember reading it in Effective Modern C++. Actually defining a destructor prevents the creation of a move constructor. Copy constructors are generated as it is brought from C++98! Thanks!